# mcrypt_ecb not $decrypted correctly when I use file_get_contents PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I have code which first I encrypted using `mcrypt_ecb` and `hten` then i send the value to another page using `file_get_contents`. but when I echo receive  data, it only print half of it. I have attached my code and result below:

Client

```
$mac="B8-AC-6F-2D-5C-23";
// encrpt the max address
$key_value = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0c"); 
$plain_text = $mac; 
$encrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $plain_text, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT); 
echo ("<p><b> Text after encryption : </b>"); 
echo ( $encrypted_text ); 

// send encrypted mac address to bridge for verification
$response = file_get_contents('http://localhost/scale/check.php?mac='.$encrypted_text);
print_r( $response );
```

Host

```
    if (isset($_GET['mac']) && $_GET['mac']) {
    $mac = $_GET['mac'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $mac;
    //decrypted recieve data 
    $key_value = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0c");
    /* @var $encrypted_text type */
    $encrypted_text = $mac;
    $decrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $encrypted_text, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
   echo ("<p><b> Text after decryption : </b>");
   echo ( $decrypted_text ); 
}
```

Result:

```
B8-AC-6F-2D-5C-23
Text after encryption : 5"ÆfÛkã–]» º"÷5Ã™(Ÿ©U
_5"ÆfÛk_ã–]»

Text after decryption : 9Bþ‚î10tçæÇ|¤
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of mcrypt_ecb is binary data, its bytes can contain arbitrary values. If you want to transfer it as an url parameter you have to encode it first. The general problem is that the url parameter parsing assumes a certain structure of the url. For example if you write `http://localhost/scale/check.php?mac=abc123&foo=bar` then PHP will see two parameters, the first one being `mac` with value `abc123`, the second being `foo` with value `bar`. But in the way you just concatenate the ciphertext to the url you could end up with the same url even if you really meant to have a parameter `mac` with the value `abc123&foo=bar`. To prevent such confusions all values have to be encoded so that certain characters do not appear. In your example the space seems to be problematic.

You can find some background on url encoding here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding .

By the way: It is generally appreciated if you only post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Given that you have issues with the transmission of your data you could remove all the encryption code. But as I've seen it now, I can't help but notice that the algorithm DES and the block cipher mode ECB is generally a very insecure choice. If you want to protect your data during transmission you can avoid all the [usual issues with home grown crypto schemes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology) by using an `https` connection (notice the "s" for "secure", which forces your http client to connect to the server using [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)).